# How to insert the multiple values in mysql using php

Tags: php, mysql

i have the mysql table 'persons'  with 3 columns as,

```
Name   Salary  Profession
```

I am sending 3 parameters with values using php get method as,

```
 $name = raj|lokesh|amar
 $salary = 10000|20000|30000
 $job = telecom|marine|shipyard
```

I have to insert them in 'persons' table as,

```
Name     Salaray  Profession

raj      10000     telecom
lokesh   20000     marine
amar     30000     shipyard
```

Can any one tell me how can i do this?

Answer (score 2):

You can turn string into an array using the [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) function.
You can surely use this in your case, using my little demonstration:

```
$name = "raj|lokesh|amar";
$salary = "10000|20000|30000";
$job = "telecom|marine|shipyard";
```

You just set the variables.
Now turn them into `exploded` arrays:

```
$name = explode("|", $name);
$salary = explode("|", $salary);
$job = explode("|", $job);
```

You basically want to get all of the words between the character `|` and turn each word into an array item, so each word will have it's own index.

now, `$name[0]` (the first array index),

```
echo $name[0]; // echoes 'raj'
echo $name[1]; // echoes lokesh'
echo $job[3]; // echoes 'shipyard';
```

And now you have to loop trough these arrays and insert it in the query:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($name); $i++) {
    echo $name[$i];
}
```

**So final solution will look like this:**

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($name); $i++) {
    $query = $pdoObject->prepare("INSERT INTO table (name, salary, profession) VALUES (:name, :salary, :jobs)");
    $query->execute(array(
        ":name" => $name[$i], 
        ":salary" => $salary[$i], 
        ":jobs" => $jobs[$i]
    );
}
```

Comment: + for PDO. Please write the equivalent in using mysqli.

Comment: @AlexanderMP Isn't mysqli is designed the same? both has the same method names for prapering, executing, both could be objects.

Comment: true, but a copy/paste with mentions to mysqli wouldn't hurt, wouldn't you say? I mean I appreciate this answer as it is, but to get more appreciation from everyone else, you have to write a more complete solution. Some of them might end up as pages that people click from search engines, and take as a guide on "how to do stuff".

Answer (score 0):

This is not a direct answer , since you haven't showed us any code.
Try something like this.

```
<?php
$name = "raj|lokesh|amar";
$salary = "10000|20000|30000";
$job = "telecom|marine|shipyard";

$name = explode("|",$name);
$salary=explode("|",$salary);
$job=explode("|",$job);

for($i=0;$i<count($name);$i++)
{
    $q = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `yourtable` VALUES ('$name[$i]','$salary[$i]','$job[$i]')");

}
```

Comment: I found it a great surprise, that answers on StackOverflow would contain advice to use outdated functionality, which the authors of PHP have warned us NOT to use.
http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php
"This extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and will be removed in the future."

Comment: We all know that but no matter how many times you tell them, people won't listen and by the way i appreciate your downvote.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use

```
$names = explode("|", $name);
$salaries = explode("|", $salary);
$professions = explode("|", $profession);
```

and then loop through the arrays ($names, $salaries, $professions) to insert the values in your database.
http://php.net/manual/fr/function.explode.php

Answer (score 0):

Like this

```
INSERT INTO `persons`(`Name`, `Salaray`, `Profession`) values('raj', '10000','telecom'),('lokesh', '20000','marine'),('amar', '30000','30000')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//ASSIGN THE VARIABLES TO INSERT
    $name= '';
    $salary='';
    $job='';
//INSERT DATA INTO DATABASE
    $Input = mysql_query('INSERT INTO persons (name, salary, profession) VALUES ($name, $salary, $job)');
//SEARCH FOR PERSONS
    $output= mysql_query('SELECT * FROM persons ORDER BY id ASC');
    $personsCount = mysql_num_rows($output); //count output amount
//LOOP PERSONS OUTPUT
    if($personsCount > 0){
        while($row=mysql_fetch_array($output)){
                $id = $row['id'];
            $name = $row['name'];
            $salary = $row['salary'];
            $job = $row['job'];

    $personsList .=  $name.'&nbsp;'.$salary.'&nbsp;'.$job.'';
    }
}

echo $personsList;
```