# Creating Form To Alter Permanent Variables

Tags: java, php, jquery, html, forms

Currently I am trying to create a webpage where the link will only be given to individuals to update values of different variables. I want the variables to, then, change the data presented on other webpages. Would a php form be the best to do this?

I'm obviously an amateur programmer/web developer, so any help would be awesome.

My setup:
I have a server and use php files to communicate different webpages to the site.

Example:

-NAME OF LOCATION- Has an OSHA Rating of $VARIABLE

The form must be able to edit many variables. It may be easier to have different forms for different sets of data, but that isn't very important at this moment, I just really need to see an example of what would work for my situation. Forms are not working for me because I do not know how to make the $_POST["VARIABLE"] become permanent.

If it helps, all data are numbers.

TIA!!!

Comment: *"because I do not know how to make the $_POST["VARIABLE"] to become permanent."* --- Once the variable(s) have been inserted into a DB, they are permanent up until an update is made and/or is deleted.

Comment: Really? Obviously I'm pretty new at programming lol.. I'll look into how to update other variables then. Thanks a lot @Fred

Comment: You can write your variables to a file (like xml) or you can insert your variables in a database.

Comment: This is what databases were created for.

Comment: @Gudgip Right now I am working off of WinSCP, where the files for my website are located (the php's). So, if I wrote the form variables to the xml, I could then pull them from other php's?

Comment: Yes, that's possible. You write it to an xml file, in other php-files you can read thesame xml file if you want to. See http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_xml_simplexml.asp

Comment: You're welcome. Have a look at this Q&A http://stackoverflow.com/q/21865289/ it may shed some light on the subject. Plus, http://stackoverflow.com/q/19196537/ and look at http://www.mustbebuilt.co.uk/php/insert-update-and-delete-with-mysqli/

Comment: Something to note and is very important is to use [**`mysqli_*` with prepared statements**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php), or [**PDO**](http://php.net/pdo) with [**prepared statements**](http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements) if you're going to use a DB.

Comment: Here are a few SQL tutorial sites you can look through http://www.sql-tutorial.net/ and http://www.mysqltutorial.org/ and of course, on `mysql.com` http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/tutorial.html

Comment: Thanks a lot, @Fred-ii- you've been awesome! I really appreciate you helping the noob lol.

Comment: Question: If the SQL server I am using has an Oracle Thin driver, does that change anything lol?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to look into session variables - they have the permanence $_POST doesn't that you're looking for.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.session.php

Comment: I think the asker wants to make them permanent for all users.